# Add Full DynamoDB Access for Lambda in SAM template for AWS Serverless Repository

Tags: aws-lambda, serverless-architecture

I want to give full DynamoDB access for lambda in AWS serverless repo. But policies templates provided by them have not these permissions

Answer (score 1):

You can get an example [here](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/examples/2016-10-31/api_backend/template.yaml)

The key part is:

```
PutFunction:
  Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
  Properties:
      Policies: AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
```